# React props from parent to children

Tags: reactjs

I'm a debutant with react, i read the doc. It's a general question.
I understand how to pass a props from a child component to a parent component. But, I don't understand how to pass a props from a parent component to the child component. [image: react props]

So in the picture, to pass a props from list to app, i do that : 
in list component :

```
interface Props {
   onCreateDoc : () => void
}
```

And in my app component : 
I call list with the props :

```
<List onCreateDoc={this.onCreateDocCb}/>
```

And i implement the function :

```
onCreateDocCb = () =>{
// code of function
}
```

But I don't know how to pass a props from app to form. How can i do that ?  Thank you

Comment: You pass it down again from app to form or use Redux/Flux/Mobx

Comment: Add a prop to Form that takes a value instead of a function. That's the general pattern for component communication in React - values and handler functions are passed down to the child through props, the handlers get called to notify the parent when something has happened.

Comment: Si if I understand, i can't do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand how to pass props then how to receive props.

You add props to your Form Component that way:

`const bar = "bar"
 const fooBar = () => console.log("fooBar")
<Form stringProps="foo" varProps={bar} funcProps={fooBar}/>`

Inside your Form Component you can acces it via `this.props.stringProps`. 
Here you find examples: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Edit: Here is a snippet with a App and a Form Component and props passed from App to Form

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const Form = ({ label })  => (
  <div style={{color: "blue"}}>{label}</div>
);

// Example class component
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {title} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{title}</div>
        <Form label="label from props" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App title="title from props" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I do that when I want to pass a props from child component to the parent component. But I want to go down my props, from app to form for example, i can't do that..